# How to reduce loop with same condition

Tags: java

how to use only one loop with the same condition

thank you

"<"  is remove the lastest character in the string

answer: check  2 two strings are equal.

Ex.
String[] a = ["a","<","b"]

"a"

""

"b"

```
      String[] input1   = {"<","<","<","<","b"};
       
      String [] input2 = {"<","a","<","<","b"};
        
      System.out.println(Isequal(input1,input2));
   
     
    public static boolean Isequal(String[] input1,String[] input2)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (String string: input1) 
        {
            
            if(!string.equals("<"))
            {
                sb.append(string);  
            }
            else if(string.equals("<") && !sb.isEmpty())
            {
                sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);  
            }  
        }

        for (String string: input2) 
        {
            
            if(!string.equals("<"))
            {
                sb1.append(string);  
            }
            else if(string.equals("<") && !sb1.isEmpty())
            {
                sb1.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);  
            }  
        }
        
        return  sb.equals(sb1);
    }
```

Comment: Extract it into a method and call the method twice?

Comment: Or don't use loops at all: `public boolean isEqual(String[] input1, String[] input2) { return Arrays.toString(input1).equals(Arrays.toString(input2)); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your String arrays are of same size you can remove the two if statements:

```
 public static boolean Isequal(String[] input1,String[] input2)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    int i=0,j=0;
    int m = input1.length;
    int n = input2.length;
    while(i<m && j<n){
        if(!input1[i].contentEquals("<")){
            sb.append(input1[i]);
        }
        else if(input1[i].equals("<") && !(sb.length() ==0))
        {
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        }
        if(!input2[j].contentEquals("<")){
            sb1.append(input2[j]);
        }
        else if(input2[j].equals("<") && !(sb1.length() ==0))
        {
            sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    if(i<m){
        if(input1[i].contentEquals("<")){
            sb.append(input1[i]);
        }
        else if(input1[i].equals("<") && !(sb.length() ==0))
        {
            sb1.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        }
        i++;

    }
    if(j<n){
        if(input2[j].contentEquals("<")){
            sb1.append(input2[j]);
        }
        else if(input2[j].equals("<") && !(sb.length() ==0))
        {
            sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);
        }

    }

    return  sb.toString().equals(sb1.toString());
}
```

Also if you are checking two string characters are equal or not you need to convert the strinbuilder to string, otherwise sb and sb1 are two differenet objects and they will not be equal even if they have same characters.